# why does the program crash while we are reading a c file lie by line in the below code?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("new1.c","r");
    for(;;)
    {
        char line[100];
        char *token;
        if (fgets(line, 80, f) == NULL) break;
        token = strtok(line, " -n");
        while (token) {
            // Do something with token, for example:
            printf("'%s' ", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " -n");
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

where am I going wrong , please guide The programs also runs with some warnings and on running the program crashes .

Comment: Which warnings do you get? Please post them as well.

Comment: "_The programs also runs with some warnings_" -- Pay attention to them. They are there for a reason.

Comment: Run in a debugger to catch the crash. Also, check if the file opened successfully. And please format you code, indentation is not significant for the compiler, but it makes it easier for humans to read.

Comment: How about checking that the file has been correctly opened.

Comment: And by the way, in your actual program you *do* have the proper `#include` files?

Comment: I just tested it: your code does not crash to me. It does not give me any warnings either, but you might invoke the compiler with a different warning level

Comment: It just works fine without any warnings

Comment: line.c: In function 'main':
line.c:11:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [ena
bled by default]
         token = strtok(line, " -n");
               ^
line.c:15:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [ena
bled by default]
             token = strtok(NULL, " -n");
                   ^

Comment: As @JoachimPileborg wrote: the warnings are because you missed out `#include <string.h>`, and you also need `#include <stdio.h>`. Without the function prototype for `strtok` available, the compiler assumes its return type is `int`.

Comment: Sir the warnings are over now but its not producing any output as per my code it should do something

Comment: @radhika Please don't add crucial information as comments, *edit your question*.

Comment: @radhika As for your problem that it doesn't show any output, that's a completely different problem and so warrant a completely new question. And for that, I suggest you read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @radhika having corrected the errors advised here it is *very* unlikely that there is "no output". That would mean there is not a single `' '` or `'-'` or `'n'` in the file. At the very least, there is a `'n'` in `"main"`. And even if not, the first call to `strtok` will return a pointer to the string you passed it, since it did'nt break it up.

Comment: @radhika the only possibilities left are a) your console output is redirected so you don't see anything, and b) the file exists but has no content.

Answer (score 2):

The warnings *and* the crash is because you haven't included the correct header files.

Before the C99 standard, compilers were allowed to guess the prototype of undeclared functions when it found one, and while compilers often gets the arguments correct the return type will always be `int`.

Now take your call of `fopen`, the compiler will guess that the arguments are two constant strings (`const char *`), but the return type will be `int` and not `FILE *` as expected. This will cause problems because a signed integer and a pointer is not the same thing, and if you're on a 64-bit platform where pointers are 64 bits and `int` is usually 32 bits, you will have major problems. All this leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which is a common cause for crashes.

To solve your problems, both the warnings and the crashes, you need to `#include` the correct header files. For the file functions (`fopen`, `printf` etc.) it's `<stdio.h>`, for the string functions (e.g. `strtok`) it's `<string.h>`.

***Always*** include the header proper header files. If you don't know which header file to include for the standard functions, search e.g. [this excellent reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if file you are opening opens correctly or not.

```
...
if (f == NULL) {
    perror("new1.c");
    return 1;
}
...
```

**EDIT** The file name in your code looks like you are trying to open a C code. Give correct name if it doesn't already have.

Comment: Sir , I have gone through the code but I am not getting why its not showing any output ?

Comment: And I will surely take care of the fact that how should I ask questions , sorry for this time .

Comment: @radhika I ran the code, and got the expected output. I don't know how you are executing it, but the code is fine.